# nginx configure can't find upload module's config while it's definitely there?

Tags: nginx, configuration

I'm trying to install nginx from source, with nginx upload module included. However I'm running to this weird error:

```
./configure --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-poll_module --with-http_stub_status_module  --with-http_perl_module --add-module=/root/dls/nginx_upload_module_2.2.0
...
**adding module in /root/dls/nginx_upload_module_2.2.0
./configure: error: no /root/dls/nginx_upload_module_2.2.0/config was found**
```

while config is definitely there:

```
root@xxxxx:~/dls/nginx-1.1.14# l -alh /root/dls/nginx_upload_module-2.2.0/config 
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000 188 2010-09-27 14:54 /root/dls/nginx_upload_module-2.2.0/config
```

How can I fix this to get nginx installed?

Comment: Perhaps just a typo in your post - but the error path has an underscore (nginx_upload_module_2.2.0), while the path your config is in uses a dash (nginx_upload_module-2.2.0).

Comment: thank you! it wasn't a typo in my post, but it was indeed a typo in the ./configure command...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the information provided, it would appear that the path specified in the configure command has an underscore (nginx_upload_module_2.2.0), while the actual path to your config has a dash (nginx_upload_module-2.2.0). Since they do not match, the config legitimately cannot be found by the configure command.